# Angular directive on div, element has no focus method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that I'm putting in a div element.  In one of my link: functions I call `element.focus()`.  I get a console error: `Object [object Object] has no method focus`.

I call alert(element the line before and it says element is `[[object HTMLDivElement]]`.

do I need to somehow cast element as a div before calling focus?

This is a directive,

```
tsUui.directive('userList', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
                    scope.something=function() {
                       elem.focus();
                    };
                }
        });
```

here's a plunkr of most of the project: http://plnkr.co/edit/SiBDuylEv1LUCuWCv5Ep?p=preview

to reproduce error: click one of the user rows, you'll get an alert(elem).  if you watch the console you'll see the focus error.

Comment: Can you post your code in Fiddle?

Comment: added some code, pretty much as described. as i said, it knows that it's an HTMLdivElement

Comment: Do you have jQuery in your project or just jqLite from angular.js?

Comment: Man, i really sorry but without to see your issue reproduced in Plunker/Fiddle we can only use words like, "suppose/maybe/". Please, save your and our time :). Where do you use directive, witch elelnt you use ... Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `$(elem).focus()`?

Comment: added a plunker above

Comment: stevuu, You got it, just need to submit an answer

Comment: Angular only passes elements in `angular.element` around. If you have jQuery included then `element` should already be a jQuery element and have the `focus` method (that jqLite doesn't have). Looks like the problem in your plunker is that jQuery should be included before angular. @stevuu's answer will work, but is more of a hack-around for the real problem.

Comment: I ran into another problem right after where I couldn't bind keydown to elem.  using $(elem).keydown fixed it, though I had to use scope.$apply to have it reflect the changes.  I'll try reversing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load jQuery before AngularJS, Angular uses jQuery insteat of the jqLite(included in AngularJS). Then you can use `elem.focus();`
Otherwise, as stevuu mentioned, you must use `$(elem).focus();`

Answer (score 0):

The link function is called prior to the element being rendered, so focus() generally won't work. Here is an example where the "link" attribute on a directive is split into "pre" and "post", for pre-link and post-link functions.

[Working Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fj59GB](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fj59GB)

```js
// this is the directive you add to any element you want to highlight after creation
Guest.directive('autoFocus', function() {
    return {
        link: {
            pre: function preLink(scope, element, attr) {
                console.debug('prelink called');
                // this fails since the element hasn't rendered
                //element[0].focus();
            },
            post: function postLink(scope, element, attr) {
                console.debug('postlink called');
                // this succeeds since the element has been rendered
                element[0].focus();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```
<input value="hello" />
<!-- this input automatically gets focus on creation -->
<input value="world" auto-focus />
```

[Full AngularJS Directive Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)